# Laplace's equation-separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions, harmonic-functions

I am looking at the $2$-D Laplace's equation 
$$\nabla^2u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x), x \in (0,a)$$
$$u(x,b)=0, x \in (0, a)$$
$$u(0,y)=u(a,y)=0, y \in (0,b)$$
The solution is in the form $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$.

By using the separation of variables, we get:

$$(1):\left\{\begin{matrix}
X''+\lambda X=0, 0<x<a\\ 
X(0)=X(a)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$(2):\left\{\begin{matrix}
Y''-\lambda Y=0, 0<y<b\\ 
Y(b)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
$$u(x,0)=X(x)Y(0)=f(x):(3)$$
$$$$
From $(1)$ we get $$\lambda_n=(\frac{n \pi}{a})^2$$
$$$$
From $(2)$ we get:
$$Y(y)=C_ne^{-\frac{n \pi}{a}y}+D_ne^{\frac{n \pi}{a}y}$$

$\sinh{(x)}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}, \cosh{(x)}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Since $Y(b)=0$:

$$Y(y)=C_n \cosh{(\frac{n \pi}{a}(b-y))}+D_n \sinh{(\frac{n \pi}{a}(y-b))}$$

Could you explain to me how we got to the last relation? I got stuck right now. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's redo this from the beginning.

We have
$$\nabla^2 u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$$
With $u=X(x)Y(y)$ this becomes:
$$X''Y + XY''=0$$
$$\frac{X''}X = - \frac {Y''}Y$$
Since either side is independent from the other, this has to be constant.
So let's define:
$$\lambda = \frac{Y''}Y$$
Then we get:
$$X''+\lambda X = 0, \quad  Y'' -\lambda Y=0$$

Solving this and with the boundary conditions for x, this becomes:
$$\lambda = \left(\frac{n\pi}a\right)^2, \quad 
X = B \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}a\right), \quad
Y = C e^{-n\pi y / a} + D e^{n\pi y / a}$$

With the boundary condition $Y(b)=0$, we get:
$$C e^{-n\pi b / a} + D e^{n\pi b / a} = 0$$
$$D = -C e^{-2n\pi b / a}$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
Y &=& C e^{-n\pi y / a} -C e^{-2n\pi b / a} e^{n\pi y / a} \\
Y &=& -C e^{-n\pi b / a}\left(e^{n\pi y / a -n\pi b / a } - e^{-n\pi y / a + n\pi b / a}\right) \\
Y &=& C'\left(e^{n\pi (y-b) / a} - e^{-n\pi (y - b) / a }\right) \\
Y &=& C''\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi (y-b)}a\right)
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! :-)

Comment: Could we also do it as followed??
$$$$
Solving the problem $Y_n(y)-(\frac{n \pi}{a})^2 Y_n=0$, we get:
$$Y_n(y)=C_ne^{\frac{n \pi y}{a}}+D_n e^{-\frac{n \pi y}{a}}$$
$$\Rightarrow Y_n(y)=A_n \sinh{(\frac{n \pi y}{a})}+B_n \cosh{(\frac{n \pi y}{a})}$$
$$Y_n(b)=0 \Rightarrow A_n \sinh{(\frac{n \pi b}{a})}+B_n \cosh{(\frac{n \pi b}{a})}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow B_n=-A_n \tanh{(\frac{n \pi b}{a})}$$
So
$$Y_n(y)=A_n \sinh{(\frac{n \pi y}{a})}-A_n \cosh{(\frac{n \pi y}{a})} \tanh{(\frac{n \pi b}{a})}$$
How can I continue so that I get $Y_n(y)=C'' \sinh{(\frac{n \pi (y-b)}{a})}$ ??

Comment: Yes. That also works. To continue, the easiest way to manipulate hyperbolic functions is to write them as exponential functions. So write for instance $\sinh A = \frac 1 2 (e^A - e^{-A})$. Use the similar formulas for $\cosh$ and $\tanh$. Then try to rewrite in the form $e^B - e^{-B}$ so you can simplify it to $\sinh$.

Comment: Why does the separation of variables `u(x,y) = F(x) G(y)` really work for Laplace's equation? Is there an explanation to justify this approach? (in 99.99% of lectures, it is taken for granted)

Comment: @C-3PO, it's really the other way around. It turns out that with this approach we can usually solve Laplace's equation. Once we've found a solution this way and can verify that it indeed solves the equation, we're done. If for some reason it doesn't work, we'll have to find another approach.

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback :)